# Fetch all events from one user on facebook, with facebook-graph-api

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I wonder what argument I should use here to retrieve all events made by a user and not just a specific event.. I can't find it anywhere in the documentation and this is the first time I've been using Facebook's Graph API.

The user has given me user_events permission, so I have the Access Token and now if I'm not out cycling the universe I only need the right argument to pass in under "event-id"...

```
$fb = new \Facebook\Facebook([
    'app_id' => '',
    'app_secret' => '',
    'default_graph_version' => 'v2.10',
]);


try {
    /* I wonder what argument I should use here to retrieve all events made by a user and not just a specific event. */
    $response = $fb->get('event-id', 'access-token');
} catch (\Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
    echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
    exit;
} catch (\Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
    echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
    exit;
}

$graphNode = $response->getGraphNode();
```

Comment: `/me/events` - the documentation for that seems to have gone from the `User` object documentation though, so not sure for how long that will still be available. And https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/event/ says, _“Access to Events on Users and Pages is only available to Facebook Marketing Partners.”_

Comment: Thanks! Damn... it works for now, but I wonder if you can turn to their partners then to get the same functionality